# why does if statement fail in flask

Tags: python, flask

i have the following flaskapp:

```
with open('env.txt') as f:
    if 'dev' in f.read():
        @app.route("/")  # default homepage for web app
        def index():
            return "Hello dev Kube"
    elif 'uat' in f.read():
        @app.route("/")
        def index():
            return "Hello uat Kube"
    elif 'prod' in f.read():
        @app.route("/")
        def index():
            return "Hello prod Kube"
    else:
        @app.route("/")
        def index():
            return "Hello Kube"
```

with the necessary imports.

in a previous file, i set the contents of env.txt to one of those three - dev, uat or prod. when it is dev, the if statement picks up the first part and displays the dev message, however if i set it to uat or prod it skips both elif parts and runs the else section. is there a better way to change what is displayed?

i have also tried using a different if statement to direct to different html templates but i get a similar issue with it only being able to pick up the first option or the else

Comment: `f.read()` will only return content once. Every time after that it returns the empty string. Save the value at top of the block (`myvar = f.read()`) and then check the value of the variable (`if 'dev' in myvar:`...)

Comment: @larsks i have tried defining the variable outside of the if statement and i still get the same

Comment: @TomWilliams And you changed all `if` and `elif` statements?

Comment: @larsks must've missed something somewhere, thats sorted it now